# Python Scipy Optimize Error "ValueError: Lengths must match to compare"

Tags: python, pandas, optimization, scipy, minimize

I have a python algorithm which works perfectly fine.  I input a minimum critieria ("MinScore") and the algorithm runs and preoduces a result.  Typical MinScore values are between 0.2 and 0.99.

However why I use scipy optimize to try and find the lowest algorithm output for a MinScore value, I get the following error: "ValueError: Lengths must match to compare".

This is how I call the Optimize function:

```
Optimal_Score = spo.minimize(BRMalg, 0.81, method='SLSQP',
options={'disp':True}, bounds=[(-1.00,1.00)])
```

This is where the algorthim errors from the Optimise process:

```
MinHoldScore = MinScore
Stocks['HOLD'] = (Stocks['HOLD'].where(Stocks['Total Score'].shift(1) < MinScore, True).where(Stocks['Total Score'].shift(1) >= MinHoldScore, False).ffill().fillna(False).astype(bool))
```

This is the full error message:

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
File "\\PYTHON CODE.py", line 327, in <module>
> Optimal_Score = spo.minimize(BRMalg, 0.81, method='SLSQP', options={'disp':True}, bounds=[(-1.00,1.00)])   
File "C:\\scipy\optimize\_minimize.py",
> line 455, in minimize constraints, callback=callback, **options)   
File "C:\Users\\scipy\optimize\slsqp.py",
> line 363, in _minimize_slsqp fx = func(x)   
File "C:\Users\\scipy\optimize\optimize.py",
> line 289, in function_wrapper return function(*(wrapper_args + args))
File "T:\\PYTHON CODE.py", line 288, in BRMalg
> Stocks[Ticker]['HOLD'] = (Stocks[Ticker]['HOLD'].where(Stocks[Ticker]['TOTAL_SCORE_'+MarketIndex+'_'+str(BetaWindow)].shift(1) < MinBuyScore, True)
File "C:\Users\\pandas\core\ops.py", 
> line 740, in wrapper raise ValueError('Lengths must match to compare') ValueError: Lengths must match to compare
```

ANy ideas?? Very strange that it all works perfectly when not using SCIPY OPTIMIZE and just passing a value of MinScore = 0.82 for example.

Look forward to your advice! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Okay I think I found the root cause here.

The [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html) state that scipy.optimize.minimize returns the optimization result represented as a OptimizeResult object. Important attributes are: x the solution array.

In your example, Optimal_Score is an object. I suspect you tried to pass Optimal_Score.x as a float to MinBuyValue, but it's actually a list.

Let me illustrate on a toy version.

```
BRMalg = lambda x: 1 + x + x ** 2 - x ** 3
Optimal_Score = minimize(BRMalg, 0.5, method='SLSQP', options={'disp': True}, bounds=[(-1.00, 1.00)])
print(Optimal_Score.x)
adict = {'Ticker': ['AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC', 'DDD', 'EEE', 'FFF'],
         'Total_Score': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
         'HOLD': [False, False, False, False, False, False]}
Stocks = pd.DataFrame(adict)
Stocks.set_index('Ticker', inplace=True)
Stocks['HOLD'] = Stocks['HOLD'].where(Stocks['Total_Score'].shift(1) < Optimal_Score.x, True)
```

This returns the pandas ValueError:

```
Optimization terminated successfully.    (Exit mode 0)
Traceback (most recent call last):
Stocks['HOLD'] = Stocks['HOLD'].where(Stocks['Total_Score'].shift(1) < Optimal_Score.x, True)
File "\pandas\core\ops.py", line 822, in wrapper raise ValueError('Lengths must match to compare')
ValueError: Lengths must match to compare
[-0.33315628]
Process finished with exit code 1
```

If we index the float from the list 'Optimal_Score.x' the issue is resolved.

```
Stocks['HOLD'] = Stocks['HOLD'].where(Stocks['Total_Score'].shift(1) < Optimal_Score.x[0], True)
Optimization terminated successfully.    (Exit mode 0)
        Current function value: [ 0.81481488]
        Iterations: 7
        Function evaluations: 21
        Gradient evaluations: 7
[-0.33315628]
```

Comment: Thanks Vtour but the where statements work pefectly fine, I have run this many times  with working data. I think the issue is with my scipy function?

Comment: The error says you are comparing different lengths in the statement:

BRMalg Stocks[Ticker]['HOLD'] = (Stocks[Ticker]   ['HOLD'].where(Stocks[Ticker]['TOTAL_SCORE_'+MarketIndex+'_'+str(BetaWindow)].shift(1) <  MinBuyScore, True)

Comment: Thanks Vtour, this looks like you might be on to something!  Currently in Hawaii but will check on my return :-)

Comment: Hey @cwse, did this end up resolving the issue? If so, please mark this response as having answered your question (:

Comment: Hi Fuzzy, I just got back.  Tried your solutioon but it didnt work. There appears to be an issue with the ordering.

Stocks[Hold}... is INSIDE the BRMalg (it is part of the algorithm) so you cant have it afterwards.

When i try do x[0] inside the algorithm for optimisation it errors (TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable)

Comment: i.e. 
'def BRMalg(MinBuyScore):
    MinHoldScore = MinScore
    Stocks['HOLD'] = (Stocks['HOLD'].where(Stocks['Total Score'].shift(1) < MinScore, True).where(Stocks['Total Score'].shift(1) >= MinHoldScore, False).ffill().fillna(False).astype(bool))'